# What's the difference between "Deployment target" and "iOS deployment target" in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, deployment, xcode4, target

I've been living in doubts since Xcode 4 release about `deployment target` option.
There are two options to set.

1. First is on "TARGETS" pane and is called `Deployment Target`. This one serves the purpose to set the lowest possible iOS version that app can run on.
2. Second is on "PROJECT" pane and is called `iOS Deployment Target`. Well, this is the one that I'm not familiar with.

Can someone please explain it to me how to properly set second option if I support let say iOS 4+ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first is related to different targets of the same project where you can define specific settings for them. It's used normally to maintain in a single project, different versions of the same core project. For example: a paid version and a trial version, you would have a target for the paid version and one target for the trial
2. Here you can define the configurations for your debug and release schemes. For example:
   [image]

You can see I added a new configuration. You will now have different settings on the actual targets:

[image]

You can also do some fun stuff, like selecting your definitions on the target, copy and paste them on a file (*.xconfig file). You can them use this file as configuration, by defining it's name:

[image]

This is particularly useful to maintain versions of the settings on the repository.

**Edit 1.0:**

I edited the second point